# Terminal keeps asking for password and sometimes showing "keychain cannot be found to store" error

Tags: macos, keychain

For example if I pull from a git repo it keeps asking my for the username and password and if I use oauth2:xxx@xxx it says "a keychain cannot be found to store oauth2."

[image]

I can see system in my keychain access.

[image]

Comment: Are there other situations when this issue occurs or is it restricted to `git`? Can you  provide the **full** error message (please redact any personal information)? Is this error a message in Terminal or a pop-up window? When did the problem start (can you relate it to an update/upgrade or app installation)? If you open Keychain Access, do you see a System keychain?

Comment: @jaume updated the question